# xsl to search for all occurences of part of the text in xml, comparing from the passed list of texts and replacing it by a node

Tags: java, xml, regex, xslt, xpath

### The input file is as below:

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <child_node1>apple mango<sub_node1>water grapes</sub_node1> banana</child_node1>
        <child_node2>Cherry mango<sub_node2>Date grapes</sub_node2> Coconut</child_node2>
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <child_node3>banana grapes apple</child_node3>  
    </node2>
    ......
</root>
```

An XSL is required which works for the below requirement.

### Requirement:

Need to pass the list of strings and each string from that list has to be checked in this input file for all occurrences of matching text. If found enclose that matched text with a tag say `<fruit>`.

### Example:

For the above input file if I pass list of Strings including: grapes, apple

### The Expected output:

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <child_node1><fruit>apple</fruit> mango<sub_node1>water <fruit>grapes</fruit></sub_node1> banana</child_node1>
        <child_node2>Cherry mango<sub_node2>Date <fruit>grapes</fruit></sub_node2> Coconut</child_node2>            
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <child_node3>banana <fruit>grapes</fruit> <fruit>apple</fruit></child_node3>    
    </node2>
    ......
</root>
```

Only the exact matching text needs to be tagged and "`<child_node1>apple mango<sub_node1>water grapes</sub_node1> banana</child_node1>`" is still valid (The Nodes and its text).

The list of input Strings may be any thing and a generic string matching approach is required which checks with each string in that list.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with it? (Asking folks to do your assignment/homework for you is going to draw down-votes. You need to show that you've made some reasonable amount of effort to learn and to solve the problem yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

i tried something that goes like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:variable name="list">apple mango</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\s+')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". = tokenize($list, '\s+')">
            <fruit><xsl:value-of select="."/></fruit>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you have to add the list of fruits to be matched as value of variable, list, separated by whitespace.